# Subdomain name for Spanish and Brazil Portuguese

Tags: internationalization, subdomain

I'm preparing localized versions of our service in Portuguese and Spanish. The only target audience for Portuguese is Brazil while Spanish has no counties preference (but, yes, main reason is Latin and South America).

So I want to create subdomains for those languages.

My first idea was to use just ISO language codes:

- pt.domain.com
- es.domain.com

But Brazil has pt-br code language, so I thought of

- pt-br.domain.com

Then I thought - isn't

- brazil.domain.com

more user friendly?
And then - isn't

- spanish.domain.com

better then es.?
Or, may be

- espanol.domain.com

would be the most precise?

Any ideas are appreciated, especially from SEO point if view.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, decide very well whether you want to create subdomains by country, by region, or by language. Even though the difference between a country and a language is very simple, people for some reason confuse them very frequently. Make this decision early on and be consistent, and you'll save yourself a lot of trouble later.

Also, are you sure that it's important for you to differentiate between the Portuguese of Brazil and its other varieties? Are you targeting people in Portugal? And even if you do, is it important to make a different translation for them? Spanish also has regional varieties - the European variety is different from the Latin American one, and there are differences between the different Latin American countries, too. And even though there are differences, both varieties are usually understandable to speakers in all regions. You need to ask people who know these languages well how important it is in your case. If it's not important, just make one version per each language.

ISO codes for countries or languages are probably better: they are shorter and you save yourself the doubts of which name to use - "espanol" or "spanish". It shouldn't matter much anyway.

I'm not a SEO expert, but common sense says that useful content should be far more important for SEO than a domain name.

Comment: In fact, I'm targegin on regions rather that on languages. That's why I thought of brazil.domain.com for Brazilian customers and that might work. However, there's no certain domain for South America which could be easily recognized by name, that's why I thought of spanish.domain.com.

Comment: And of course you're right - content is the primary goal of any language site. But that's not a problem  - this will be just a translation of English site.

Comment: After all we decided to have simple two-character ISO-code language-based domains and leave soecific countries targeting to further SEO activities.
FYI - new domains are https://pt.wmspanel.com/ and https://es.wmspanel.com/ (both under construction yet)
Thanks for your opinion!